# Removing multiple HTML elements without removing what's in between them

Tags: regex

I'm using this regex to rewrite some HTML to remove script tags:

```
<script(.|\n)*\/script>
```

It works, but there's a problem when there's multiple scripts, for example:

```
<script> JS </script>
Other Stuff
<script> JS </script>
```

In this case the "Other Stuff" is removed. How do I just remove the script tags and their contents without removing the "Other Stuff" too?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<script((?!<\/script>).)*<\/script>
```

Try this.See demo.

http://regex101.com/r/uH3tP3/2

Answer (score 0):

```
<script>.*<\/script>
```

use with multiline and global

http://regex101.com/r/qU9vS8/1